# Choose <li> insertion place in list with jQuery according to id of siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a regular html ordered list:

```
<nav id="global_nav">
    <ol class="menu">
    <li id="Section1">Section1</li>
    <li id="Section2">Section2
    <ol>
        <li id="subsection1">Subsection1</li>
            <li id="subsection2">Subsection2</li>
           <li id="subsection3">Subsection3</li>
      </ol>
      </li>
      <li id="Section3" >Item3</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

and I made a small html form too:

```
<form>
    <label for="nuevo">Insert</label>
    <input type="text" id="nuevo">
    <label for="despues">After the section</label>
    <input type="text" id="despues">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Insert">
</form>
```

The point is to be able to populate the list dinamically using jQuery. For example, if in the text field 1 I type 'Section4' and in the text field 2 I type 'Section3', the function will add a new `<li>`element with the text 'Section4' right after the already existing 'Section3'.

I have done this, and it kind of works ok:

```
    $("#btn").click(function(){

    var nuevo=$('#nuevo').val();
    //var despues=$('#despues').val();
    var nl = $('<li></li>').text(nuevo).attr('id', nuevo ).slideDown();

    $(".menu").append(nl);
```

But as you see, I have commented out the line grabbing the value of the second text field, because I cannot understand how should I make the reference to the sibling item that will determine the placement of the new item. For instance, if the first item I attach is "Section7" and it goes appended to the very bottom of the list, how can I attach a "Section6" later on right before "Section7"?

What jQuery functions would you say that I need to use in order to get going with this? Up to now I only knew a bit of pure javascript. I am trying to understand all the cool things with jQuery but in this case I am finding in the docs a lot of functions that are apparently very similar, so I am quite confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle for the same. I hope this helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/zy1f7ohc/5/

```
$("#btn").click(function(){

    var nuevo=$('#nuevo').val();
    var despues=$('#despues').val();

     $('<li></li>').text(nuevo).attr('id', nuevo).insertAfter("#"+despues);

 });
```

Comment: Just a note (more to the OP), the slideDown isn't going to do anything as the element is not yet visible in the DOM. You'd have to insert it with display: none, the call slideDown.

Comment: Agreed. Actually I am not even using that. Just forgot to remove it.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't really paying attention to the slideDown because I was focused on fixing the other thing. Good catch, I will fix it.

Comment: @telex-wap - please mark an answer as correct so that others who refer to your post get help!

Comment: I just noticed that your fiddle is not working with Subsections. I am trying to find out what's the reason...

Comment: Its working. Are you entering the value in the second textbox right? Its all small letters.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
 $(".menu").append(nl);
```

You are **always** adding your new list item to the **very end of the the whole menu**.

Try this instead for inserting it after the value for "nuevo" (after uncommenting the "despues" line):

```
 $("#" + despues).after(nl);
```

For before, assume you have another text input with id "antes":

```
 $("#" + antes).before(nl);
```

In these examples, we're adding the element immediately next to (or before) the item you specified by id rather than appending it to the end of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue has been explained in other answers.

However, I'd do it differently. I'd use `select` instead of `input`, because the user experience would be terrible when typing elements into text box like that (while it can be easily automated with `select`).
That way it will be much easier to use and far more accessible for the user.

*SIDE NOTE:*
Better make sure that the inputed `id` does not exist in the DOM already. You definitely don't want to have multiple elements with the same `id`.

```
function selectSet(){
    var d = $('#despues').empty();
    $('.menu li').each(function(){
        var txt = $.trim($($(this).contents()[0]).text());
        d.append('<option value="'+this.id+'">'+txt+'</option>');
    });
    // set last option as selected by default:
    $('option:last', d).prop('selected', true);
}
// set select box dynamically:
selectSet();

$("#btn").click(function(){
    var nuevo = $('#nuevo').val(),
        despues = $('#despues').val(),
        // make unique id (simple version):
        id = nuevo + ($('.menu li').length + 1);
    // hide and slideDown the new element, so that you can see the animation:
    $('<li id="'+id+'">'+nuevo+'</li>').insertAfter("#"+despues).hide().slideDown();
    // update select box:
    selectSet();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/en1p58j6/)

Comment: Thank you, this project I am doing is all set to use `input` rather than `select`, but your explanation has been useful to learn extra concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to simplify your code a little bit. Type in the following snippet a text and a section (for example "B" to append something after the list item "B"):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var arr = [];
  //Store every value from each input (two values)
  $("input").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
  });
  //loop through every list item
  $("li").each(function(){
    //create a new node with the text stored in the array on the first index (0)
    var newli = document.createElement("li");
    newli.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[0]));
    //If the html fits the second index in the array (means the value from the second input) we append the node after that item
    ($(this).html() === arr[1]) ? $(this).append(newli) : null;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <ol>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
  </ol>
  <li>2</li>
</ol>
<input>Text</input>
<input>Section</input>
<button>Send</button>
```

What we do here is creating an array to store the two input values. After that we loop through every "li" element to find the one we're searching for. If the html fits, we can append a additional node after the particular list item.

What's interesting here is the node creation. You are able to find a complete reference here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Also check out this function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Even though today is just my second day with jQuery and your answer looks a bit dense, I will give it another look because it sounds like an interesting method.

Comment: May I recommend you to learn pure javascript before you do it with jQuery? The other way around is a lot more pain :) http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Comment: Oh, I already have a certain level of javascript (not very advanced, though). I just got started with jQuery out of curiosity because of its possibilities. Thanks for your links!